# Ruby: split data from string

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a string format like this:

```
{country}_{verification_type}_{account_type}
```

The `country`:

- sg
- jp

The `vericiation_type`:

- myinfo
- myinfo_with_address
- default

The `account_type`:

- personal
- account_manager
- beneficial_owner

How can I split from a string to get those 3 information?

Let say the string is: sg_myinfo_with_address_account_manager, it has to be splitted as:

```
country: "sg"
verification_type: "myinfo_with_address"
account_type: "account_manager"
```

It seems the best way are to use regex and match. But I have no idea how to make the regex.

One by one is fine. Let say:

```
str = "sg_myinfo_with_address_account_manager"
{
  country: str.match("country regex"),
  verification_type: str.match("verification_type regex"),
  account_type: str.match("account_type regex")
}
```

Comment: Is there any good reason that your source string needs to needs to use underscores to delimit the substrings?  In addition, is there any particular reason the 3 pieces of information need to be stored in a string as opposed to an array or a hash?

Comment: @MichaelB This is legacy code, already has millions of this string in the database.

Comment: Are the possible verification types fixed, or could there be that one day you get a new verification type?

Comment: @user1934428 one day will get a new country, verification_type, and also account_type. Rizwan's answer is good enough to solve my problem, but I really open if there are better solutions.

Comment: I'm just wondering: If you have the underscore acting as a separator between the fields, but also a valid chacracter inside verification type and account type, how can you in general recognize the fields in, i.e., `A_B_C_D_E_F`? Is it `A`, `B_C`, `D_E_F`, or maybe `A`, `B_C_D`, `E_F`? Or are you simply putting the new possible values into your regexp literally?

Comment: @user1934428 for now I put the values in regexp literally. Those values can be put as constants. So we won't have unknown values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
^(sg|jp)_(myinfo|myinfo_with_address|default)_(personal|account_manager|beneficial_owner)$
```

and replace it by this:

```
country: "\1"\nverification_type: "\2"\naccount_type: "\3"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4O5kfj/1/)

Ruby Source:

```
re = /^(sg|jp)_(myinfo|myinfo_with_address|default)_(personal|account_manager|beneficial_owner)$/m
str = 'sg_myinfo_with_address_account_manager
'
subst = 'country: "\\1"\\nverification_type: "\\2"\\naccount_type: "\\3"'

result = str.gsub(re, subst)

puts result
```

Comment: I made some adjustments based on your answer. Thanks!